# Why Ubuntu kernel will not get major updates?

Tags: kernel, updates

I have 12.04(for ia32-libs) and 15.04 beside win8 and XP :)

When I update the Ubuntu, for example 15.04, the kernel changes form 3.18.x to 3.18.y, while Ubuntu 15.10 uses kernel 4.2.x. Ubuntu 12.04.5 support is till 2019 and they are available(thanks to it's developers), but the kernel updates are minor for example: from 3.19.x-20 to 3.19.x-22.

There is lots of bugs which has been fixed in the newer kernels.

Why the oldest versions can't migrate to newer kernel?

I need 12.04 for it's great compatibility with 32bit apps, but I want the latest stable kernel.
I know I can build the kernels for my Ubuntu, but the officials are better than mine.

Comment: It has already got upgrades starting from the 3.2 kernel it originally had.

Comment: This is because 12.04 is only getting bug fixes and security updates, it is not in development like 15.10, you can see from the version numbers it is getting incremental updates to the current version and not whole new kernel versions, this will also be true for many other packages on your system. LTS is about stability not having the latest packages.

Comment: @mark kirby, I got, but "LTS is about stability not having the latest packages" means kernel 4.2 is not stable and it's still under development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Ubuntu supported kernels get bug fixes and security updates backported from new upstream kernels.

LTS Ubuntu versions have an option to get new kernels form non-LTS releases. See [HWE Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack).

If you like, you can install any mainline kernel manually from [Ubuntu mainline kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/).

In this case you will have to install updates manually.